# Pasar campo cadena a formulario modal bootstrap

Tags: php, json, bootstrap

¿Podrían ayudarme a resolver este problema que tengo por favor?

Lo que intento hacer es pasar el Nombre del cliente desde el campo `$row['NomRazSoc']` del archivo "`listar.php`", al formulario modal "`clientes.php`" pasando como parámetro el valor de cadena de dicho campo a través de la función "`jsElimReg(name)`", de manera que me aparezca ese valor en la etiqueta span que tiene el identificador id="nombre-recibido" pero no lo muestra, y solo muestra campos númericos como el de `$row['IdCliente']`

¿Alguien podría decirme por qué no muestra valores de cadena?

---

Archivo `listar.php`

```
<?php

$actionButton = '
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Acción <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalModificar" onclick="jsModiReg('.$row['IdCliente'].')" style="cursor:pointer;"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style="color:purple"></span>&nbsp;Modificar</a></li>
        <li><a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalEliminar" onclick="jsElimReg('.$row['NomRazSoc'].')" style="cursor:pointer;"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="color:red"></span>&nbsp;Eliminar</a></li>      
    </ul>
</div>
';

?>
```

---

Archivo `clientes.js`

```
function jsElimReg(name) {
$("#nombre-recibido").append(name);
}
```

---

Archivo `clientes.php`

```
<!-- INICIO DE FORMULARIO MODAL ELIMINAR REGISTRO -->
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="ModalEliminar" style="margin-top:50px;">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="height:48px;padding-top:8px;background-color:#347ab6;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="color:#ffffff;"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="font-size:24px;color:#ffffff;"></i>&nbsp;<span style="color:#ffffff;">Eliminar Registro</span></h4>           
      </div>          
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><center><span style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;">¿Está seguro de querer eliminar el registro selecionado?</span></center></p>
        <p><center><span style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;" id="nombre-recibido"> </span></center></p> 
      </div>              
      <div class="modal-footer" style="height:48px;padding-top:6px;background-color:#e6e6e6;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" style="font-size:18px;color:white"></i>&nbsp;Cerrar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" tabindex="62"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" style="font-size:18px;color:white"></i>&nbsp;Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<!-- FIN DE FORMULARIO MODAL ELIMINAR REGISTRO -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En esta parte de tu codigo:

```
 <li><a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalEliminar"   onclick="jsElimReg('.$row['NomRazSoc'].')" style="cursor:pointer;"> <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="color:red"></span>&nbsp;Eliminar</a></li>
```

al metodo jsElimReg, tu intencion es pasarle el nombre que es una cadena, pero lo que pasa es que le estas pasando la cadena sin comillas, y en realidad lo que queda es esto: jsElimReg( Anzai) por ejemplo, agregale comillas para que lo reciba bien:

```
    <li><a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalEliminar"   onclick="jsElimReg(\''.$row['NomRazSoc'].'\')" style="cursor:pointer;"> <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="color:red"></span>&nbsp;Eliminar</a></li>
```

y deberia verse finalmente asi  jsElimReg( 'Anzai') 
Prueba reemplazar lo de arriba en la cadena que usas para mostrar el HTML

Comment: Sonia Toledo, te Agradezco Enormemente tu Gran Apoyo, tu respuesta me ha Solucionado el Problema, PERO....AHORA Resulta que en el formulario modal me aparece el nombre del cliente anterior cada que selecciono uno nuevo, así: nombre cliente 1 Nombre cliente 2 nombre cliente 3, etc ¿Cómo Limpio la cadena con el nombre del cliente seleccionado anteriormente, es decir, que No se me concatenen?

Comment: YA encontré la solución a la concatenación que se presentaba, esta fue simplemente adicionar la línea "$("#nombre-recibido").html("");" a la función "jsElimReg(name)" del Archivo "clientes.js". GRACIAS!